# Recyclerview IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a chat application in which when a new chat is created, there are no messages in the message list. When the user goes in the chat and the first message is sent. The app crashes with the following error code

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{213d192 position=3 id=-1, oldPos=1, pLpos:1 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5297)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5479)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3534)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3310)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:636)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2198)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

The following is my code for attaching the adapter to the recyclerview.

```
mMessageAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(currentConversationKey, this, this);
    conversationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(messageLinearLayout);
    conversationRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    conversationRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
    mConversationRecyclerDataObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversation Adapter is changed");
            checkIfMessagesInConversation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversation Adapter item range changed");
            checkIfMessagesInConversation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversation Adapter item range inserted");
            checkIfMessagesInConversation();
            int messageCount = mMessageAdapter.getItemCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "message Count is : "+ messageCount);
            int lastVisiblePosition = messageLinearLayout.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.d(TAG, "Last Visible Position is : "+ lastVisiblePosition);

            Log.d(TAG, "positionStart is : "+ positionStart);

            Log.d(TAG, "Insert Item count  : "+ itemCount);

            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (messageCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling to pos "+ (messageCount - 1));
                try {
                    conversationRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mMessageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
            if(isRefreshing){
                onItemsLoadComplete();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversation adapter item range removed");
            checkIfMessagesInConversation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition, toPosition, itemCount);
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversation Adapter item range moved");
            checkIfMessagesInConversation();
        }
    };
    mMessageAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(mConversationRecyclerDataObserver);
```

Please help

Comment: Please add source code of MessagesAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh list every time you add or remove something from the list with one of the many methods available in the RecyclerView:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

> final void    notifyDataSetChanged() 
>   Notify any registered observers that
>   the data set has changed.
>
> final void    notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload) 
>   Notify any
>   registered observers that the item at position has changed with an
>   optional payload object.
>
> final void    notifyItemChanged(int position) 
>   Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed.
>
> final void    notifyItemInserted(int position) 
>   Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at position has been  > newly inserted.
>
> final void    notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) 
>   Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at fromPosition has
>   been moved to toPosition.
>
> final void    notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount,
>   Object payload) 
>   Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at position > positionStart have changed.
>
> final void    notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)
>   Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at
>   position positionStart have changed.
>
> final void    notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
>   Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected itemCount
>   items starting at positionStart have been newly inserted.
>
> final void    notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
>   Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items previously
>   located at positionStart have been removed from the data set.
>
> final void    notifyItemRemoved(int position) 
>   Notify any registered observers that the item previously located at position > has been removed from the data set.

Without looking into more details I would say that your problem occurs when you try scrolling to the last item. Try refresh the dataset before scrolling and see what happens:

```
  Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling to pos "+ (messageCount - 1));
            try {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                conversationRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mMessageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `conversationRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` with `conversationRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);`